# Reading from text file creates three dots

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am reading a long text file containing a sql query using StreamReader then using StringBuilder to create a string that gets run against a database.  Once the string is created I checked the value and three dots ... appear within the string causing the query to fail when I run it against the database.  Why is this happening?  What can I do to keep it from  happening?

```
string script;
if (File.Exists(path))
{

    using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            sb.Append(sr.ReadLine());

        }
        script = sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: I should add that the three dots appear at character position 16384 every time.  Not sure of the significance of this

**UPDATE**: It appears the string is being truncated at runtime.  the file contiains 48080 characters but is being truncated in the middle at position 16384 making the string variable 32768.. Is this the max character count for a string?

Comment: Did you debug ? Is all of the other text read perfectly without any problems ? If so are you sure your text doesn't have these dots ? And why not instead of reading from a text file to pass a query in sql just make a stored procedure ?

Comment: Unfortunately in my situation I do not have the rights to make a sp (I am  not to happy about since it would make my life a lot simpler).  I have checked my file and the three dots do not appear anywhere.  Also, whats even stranger, when I write the string to a text the three dots do not appear.  They are only there in the string variable

Comment: In reference to your second question, yes the rest of the text (before and after) appears to be read correctly.  I wonder if there is a hidden character that may be doing this... I have checked in notepad++ but am unable to find anything

Comment: You know that you could just do `string script = File.ReadAllText(path);`?

Comment: I think that it's unfair that this question was downvoted.  The OP clearly stated what appears to be going wrong and this question has a clear answer, which I posted below. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a definite answer for you: Microsoft says that what you are experiencing is a bug in Visual Studio 2015.  They have released an "Update 2" for Visual Studio 2015 that is reported to correct the issue.

I am trying to get this update installed by my admin, but in the meantime, a feasible workaround is to load the text in the JSON Visualizer instead.  It will show an error that it is, of course, not valid JSON since it is SQL, but it will display the whole text of the string.

Download Update 2 from here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

See the bug report here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2016177/text-visualizer-misses-corrupts-text-in-long-strings

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while I was debugging the very long query string.

It turns out, Visual Studio(mine is 2015) Debugger will truncate long strings after certain amount of characters for ease of reading. So even though you are seeing three dots(...) in Text Visualizer, actual value doesn't have that three dots.

To my knowledge, visual studio 2012 debugger doesn't add three dots. I haven't found a way how to turn the feature off in VS2015, but you can use html visualizer or json visualizer as alternative solution.

[image: Use html visualizer or json visualizer like this]

Comment: It's not a feature.  It's a bug :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that you are checking the values in your debugger, where the long query text is being partially shown and ends with an ellipsis (...)

Again guessing here, but seems like you join your lines of SQL into one single line, and if the lines in the file do not end with whitespace character, then the query will get messed up. Probably that is the reason why your SQL query does not work.

By the way, you can write the code you have far more succinctly as below

```
if (File.Exists(path))
    script = string.Join(" ", File.ReadLines(path));
```

Comment: Yea, I thought that as well as far as the ellipsis but when I use the text visualizer in VS I can see the ... being appended and not in the same place every time.  I rewrote the code as you suggested with no success

Comment: @brdahlgren I would suggest you to try it with a simple SQL query

Comment: I tried that and with a simple query it doesn't add the three dots.  I should correct my previous comment, I tried reading files of various length and the three dots do appear a char position 16,384 everytime